# Async function does not wait AsyncStorage in useEffect hook. React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await, use-effect, asyncstorage

I'm trying to retrieve my fake token ('successful_fake_token') by using AsyncStorage, which I can get well, but after the .then block finished his work.

```
function loadUsers() {
        setUsers({ users: [], hasLoadedUsers: false, userLoadingErrorMessage: '' });
        getUsers().then( (res) =>
            setUsers({
                users: res.users,
                hasLoadedUsers: true,
                userLoadingErrorMessage: ''
            })
        ).catch(handleUserLoadingError(res));
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        loadUsers();
    }, []);

function handleUserLoadingError(res) {
        if (res.error === 401) {
            props.navigation.navigate('Login');
        } else {
            console.log('hanlde erreur');
            setUsers({
                users: [],
                hasLoadedUsers: false,
                userLoadingErrorMessage: res.message,
            });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Don't handle errors by doing `return null`, unless you don't actually need the token - in which case you wouldn't need to call the `getToken` function in the first place.

Comment: The error message is clear and correct. In `.catch(handleUserLoadingError(res))`, `res` is not defined. What does `handleUserLoadingError` do and how is it defined, maybe you meant `catch(handleUserLoadingError)`?

Comment: Oh my god you're right @Bergi, the problem come from `.catch(handleUserLoadingError(res))` which should be `catch(handleUserLoadingError)`